# 0.501 in the C++ rounding algorithm, Excel ROUND in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, floating-point, rounding

I have the following legacy code for usual rounding (round half up, rounding like in Excel ROUND function). I have the questions about this code.

1. why 0.50x addition is used? I understand, that 0.5 addition should be used to implement "round half up" condition, but why there is 0.501? Our experience shows that 0.501 works good in practice, it introduces far less rounding errors (those cases when RoundFloat differs from Excel ROUND) than 0.5. Why is that? Are floating point calculations biased to give smaller values than in ideal case and 0.501 corrects those biases?
2. While 0.501 works good in most cases, there are problems for some values, e.g. RoundFloat(7.33499999999, 2) gives 7.34, but that is wrong, the right answer should be 7.33. How to improve algorithm to achieve right results? One can try to use 0.50000001 instead of 0.501, but there always be arguments which gives wrong result with such algorithm. **What is correct algorithm and is there built-in C++ function for the Excel style ROUND rounding.**

Thanks in advance!

```
double LongLong( double value ) {
  long long l = ( long long ) value;
  return l;
}

double RoundFloat( double * value, double * tonearest ) {
  double ad;
  long long mzr; 
  double resval;
  if ( ( *tonearest < 0 ) || ( *tonearest > 6 ) ) return * value;

  if ( *value < 0.000000001 )
    ad = -0.501; 
  else
    ad = 0.501;  

  mzr = LongLong(*value);   
  resval = *value - mzr;

  switch ( ( long ) *tonearest )
  {   
   case 0 : resval= LongLong( resval+ad);
   case 1 : resval= LongLong( resval*10+ad)/10;
   case 2 : resval= LongLong( resval*100+ad)/100;
   case 3 : resval= LongLong( resval*1000+ad)/1000;
   case 4 : resval= LongLong( resval*10000+ad)/10000;
   case 5 : resval= LongLong( resval*100000+ad)/100000;
   case 6 : resval= LongLong( resval*1000000+ad)/1000000;
   default: resval= resval;
  }
   resval = resval+mzr;
   return resval;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

(I'm restricting this answer to IEEE754 floating point, which is what Excel uses.)

0.5 (the rounding *pivot*) is used by Excel since that's the correct thing to do. Note that 0.5 (as a dyadic rational) *can* be represented exactly in floating point.

Using 0.501 is arbitrary, unduly asymmetrical, and demonstrates a lack of understanding of floating point.

You *can* get some spurious effects due to a number being a little less than 0.5 having 0.5 as the closest representable number. So your "little less" number gets rounded up even though it really ought to be rounded down. But that's more to do with the fact that the number cannot be represented exactly in the first place. So although 0.5 will give you some odd effects, it will be more accurate *on average* than 0.501 or similar. And doing something like adding more than 0.5 will mess up the cases where rounding down is optimal.

Although I've concentrated on 0.5, all rounding effects can be explained in the same way, although in other cases the rounding pivot might itself not be representable.

Learn to live with the effect, as Excel does. (Remember that Excel has the luxury of formatting the data in a way that hides these effects from the user, so it appears to be doing something more special than it actually is.) If it's absolutely critical that the calculation is accurate to beyond 15 significant figures, then use a class that supports arbitrary precision.